# Unable to change current threads UICulture - stuck on en-US

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, globalization

I am trying to implement a culture switch for the user on a website, where he can choose his preferred language from a dropdownlist.

The [problem and solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201029/propagting-the-resource-culture-change-in-master-page-to-the-content-web-pages) seemed like a good starting point, so I implemented the code into my global.asax:

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup                                                            
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];
        if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        }
    }
```

So, if no cookie is set, set the culture to `de-DE`. After this I took the second piece of code and copied it, into the `Page_Load` method of my master site:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Session["ddindex"] != null)
    {
        ddlanguage.SelectedValue = Session["ddindex"].ToString();
        ddlanguage.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ddindex"].ToString());
        //display current values in dummy label - remove later on.
        currentCulture.Text = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    }
    else
    {
        ddlanguage.SelectedValue = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    }
}
```

plus the `SelectedIndexChanged` method for the DropdDownBox:

```
protected void ddlanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["language"] = ddlanguage.SelectedValue;
    //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = ddlanguage.SelectedValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    //Set the culture and reload for immediate effect.
    //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlanguage.SelectedValue);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlanguage.SelectedValue);

    if (cookie.Value == "en-US")
    {
        Session["ddindex"] = "0";
    }
    else if (cookie.Value == "de-DE")
    {
        Session["ddindex"] = "1";
    }
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
}
```

And the markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlanguage" runat="server" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlanguage_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                  AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="en-US" Text="English"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="de-DE" Text="Deutsch"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a few values set in my resources for some `<asp:Hyperlinks>` which get properly translated from German into English upon calling the website. 
However, upon switching the current selected culture via the `asp:dropdownbox`, the culture stays on en-US (the default browser culture on my dev machine). The label `currentCulture.Text` also stays on en-US and all translations are still in English.

What am I possibly doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Override the InitializeCulture and do it from there instead in Page_Load.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("<Culture Name Here>");

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Ahh, I didn't know you want to use it on a Masterpage. Anyway, you can create a module and register it in your web.config.

```
namespace YourNameSpaceHere
{
    public class LanguageModule : IHttpModule
    {

        public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.AcquireRequestState += OnAcquireRequestState;
        }

        public void OnAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            HttpApplication httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;

            string lang = null;
            if (httpApplication.Request.Cookies["<CookieNameHere>"] == null)
            {
                lang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
                httpApplication.Response.Cookies["<CookieNameHere>"].Value = lang;
            }
            else
            {
                lang = httpApplication.Request.Cookies["<CookieNameHere>"].Value;
            }

            if (lang != Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
            {
                if (Language.IsValidCultureInfoName(lang))
                {
                    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);

                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

                    httpApplication.Response.Cookies["<CookieNameHere>"].Value = lang;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

web.config under system.web and I think system.webServer

```
<httpModules>
    <add type="YourNameSpaceHere.LanguageModule, YourNameSpaceHere" name="LanguageHandlerModule" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: While this is totally valid for normal pages, it does not apply for MasterPages; which unfortuntly can't inherit from a BasePage class, which would in turn derive from System.Web.UI.Page.

Comment: Your custom handler works per se on my master page, but translations do not work on normal 0815 pages. I can translate evertything on master sites on the fly, but f.e. content in default.aspx refuses to get its values from meta:resourcekey="" values

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
Take a look at this Microsoft Bug: [Race condition in System.Resources.ResourceManager leads to incorrect resources being loaded](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806505/)

Take a look at the workaround I've posted there.

Basically, there's a problem with the resource manager where an internal race condition causes it to load all cultures as the en-US culture.

What I did, in an MVC project, was to "initialize" all resource sets when the application starts. The following code is from my `Global.asax` file, in the `MvcApplication` class's `Application_Start()` method:

```
Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), true, true);
Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"), true, true);
Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), true, true);
Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("he-IL"), true, true);
```

This will force the resource manager to load correctly. It sucks, but it doesn't seem like Microsoft is giving this bug any attention.

You need to add a line like in the code above for each culture you have.
I'm not sure where to put this code in an ASP.NET **non MVC** application, though. Just find the starting point of the application and put it there.

Comment: WebFroms web applications do have a Global.asax file as well, don't worry. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Nope. I was able to get the globalization going on the master pages, but every .aspx page ignores the globalization-provider